# CSS Canonical for "pseudo elements need a content property"

Tags: discussion, canonical

This is a somewhat common problem that crops up every now and then where the asker doesn't realize they need to set the content property on pseudo elements in order to bring them to life.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a definitive canonical to use when closing them as duplicates.

Here's the best options I've been able to find:

## [Pseudo-element after not showing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783361/pseudo-element-after-not-showing)

The question itself is terrible, the OP made absolutely no attempt at solving the problem (no wonder why your pseudo element doesn't show, you didn't write any code for it!).  The answer clearly emphasizes the most likely cause as to why the code they didn't provide doesn't work.  This question is from 2013 and has pretty good search ranking on Google (relatively speaking).

## [after pseudo element not appearing in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29572730/after-pseudo-element-not-appearing-in-code)

This question is quite new (it's from this year) and has example code that actually illustrates the problem.  The provided answers actually point to the "why" you need to do this from the specification.

Other random duplicates:

- [Avoid applying style to :after when using :hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34047904/avoid-applying-style-to-after-when-using-hover)
- [Is it possible to have a :after pseudo element on a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18767633/is-it-possible-to-have-a-after-pseudo-element-on-a-button)

Are there any other better prospects than this?

Comment: because why write good questions when even terrible ones get good rankings on SERPs anyway?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9599811/why-do-i-need-an-empty-content-property-on-an-after-pseudo-element and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067918/why-do-pseudo-elements-require-a-content-property

Comment: Those are excellent candidates, @TylerH.